# Issue with Silverlight 5 beta and Silverlight April 2010 Toolkit

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-toolkit, silverlight-5.0

There seems to be an issue with SL 5 beta and the SL April 2010 Toolkit.

After converting a Silverlight Solution (which compiled well under SL 4!) to SL5 I get the following error:

> The tag 'TreeViewDragDropTarget' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.Toolkit'

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know, but post updates when you find out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://marktinderholt.wordpress.com/2011/07/12/silverlight-toolkit-for-silverlight-5-beta

Answer (score 0):

http://forums.silverlight.net/p/215249/509930.aspx

Someone with a similar problem, his solution was to re-download and reinstall the toolkit. I'd say give it a shot. Though this seems like a common problem between many versions of Silverlight not just 5. I hope this helps.